# neo4j col Node (a) -[:r)->b

Tags: neo4j, cypher

Giving this Neo4j graph:

// Create the Node A-----------------------------------------------

MERGE (x:A  {name : '01-A'} )

MERGE (x:A  {name : '02-A'} )

MERGE (x:A  {name : '03-A'} )

MERGE (x:A  {name : '04-A'} )

MERGE (x:A  {name : '05-A'} )

// Return the Five Node-----------------------------------------------

MATCH (x:A) return x

// Create the Node B-----------------------------------------------

MERGE (y:B  {name : '01-B'} )

MATCH (x:B) return x

// Establish Relation Ship-----------------------------------------------

Match (x:A {name : '01-A'}),(y:B {name : '01-B'}) merge (x)<-[r:C]-(y)

Match (x:A {name : '03-A'}),(y:B {name : '01-B'}) merge (x)<-[r:C]-(y)

Match (x:A {name : '05-A'}),(y:B {name : '01-B'}) merge (x)<-[r:C]-(y)

// Display the Relation Ship

match ()-[r]-(y:B  {name : '01-B'}) return type(r)

type(r)

"C"

"C"

"C"

// display the Node A with relation ship with Node B

match (x:A)-[r:C]-(y:B) where  ((x)-[*]-(y)) return x

{
  "name": "05-A"
}
{
  "name": "03-A"
}
{
  "name": "01-A"
}

// Display the A Nodes does not have relation ship Node B

match (x:A)-[r:C]-(y:B) where  NOT ((x)-[*]-(y)) return x

(no changes, no records)

------------>
This is false because Node A2 and Node A4 does not have relation with B1 
<-----------

Any solution?

Comment: You've given a path with variables. There's nothing in here about node labels, node properties, or even relationship types, which you would need established first to answer the questions you presented.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or add additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it’s hard to tell exactly what you're asking. See the [How to Ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) page for help clarifying this question.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for the updated description.

The problem is that your MATCH has already selected nodes which fit the pattern.

```
match (x:A)-[r:C]-(y:B) 
where NOT ((x)-[*]-(y)) 
return x`
```

This is a nonsensical query. You are asking for any :A and :B nodes in the graph that are connected by a relationship :C where the nodes aren't connected, no such pattern could ever exist.

From your description, you want to `Display the A Nodes does not have relation ship Node B`. Here's how you would query for this:

```
match (x:A)
where not (x)-[:C]-(:B) 
return x
```

If you didn't care about the relationship type, you could omit that part:

```
match (x:A)
where not (x)--(:B) 
return x
```

If you wanted no possible path between :A and a :B node, then you would use `*` to indicate a path of any size between an :A node and any :B node:

```
match (x:A)
where not (x)-[*]-(:B) 
return x
```

Comment: wow. Really Appreciate the Explanation of the Relation. Any Document that you can recommend to better master this relationship.

Comment: The developers manual has good examples for [match](https://neo4j.com/docs/developer-manual/current/cypher/clauses/match/) and on [using patterns in the where clause](https://neo4j.com/docs/developer-manual/current/cypher/clauses/where/#query-where-patterns). In general the developer manual should be your first resource when learning cypher (along with the examples available in the browser). The [cypher refcard](https://neo4j.com/docs/cypher-refcard/current/) will be a helpful reference too.